# Repeat a custom element in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an application where i have to repeat a custom component say 200 times on a single page and save the reference of each component. I tried adding it using for loop, but doing so is giving me a script error. Is there any other way to repeat a custom component in extjs?
Here is the code i am using.

```
Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'Excel',

launch: function() {
    Ext.define('ExcelCell',{
           extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
           itemcls: 'excelCell',
           height: 20,
           width: 64
        });

    var port = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'absolute'
    });


    var totalRowsToDraw = port.height/20;
    var totalColumnsToDraw = port.width/64;

    var cellDictionary = new Object();
    var cell;

    for(var r=0; r < totalRowsToDraw ;r++){
        for(var c=0; c < totalColumnsToDraw ;c++){
            cell = Ext.create('ExcelCell');
            cell.x = c*64;
            cell.y = r*20;
            port.add(cell);
            cellDictionary[r+','+c] = cell;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Also my Css code is

```
.excelCell{
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
padding-top: 0;
border: 1;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #B7BABC;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XGdu9/ (but I think you rather use an `XTemplate` or `container`s or `box`s instead of `panel`s)

Comment: When i am using Hbox or Vbox i am not getting the border only for panel i am getting the borders around the cell. I am a newbie to ExtJs so i don't have in depth knowledge why is it happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. The only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe you want to use `cellDictionary` from other methods.

If that's the case, and you want to make it globally accesible, instead of:

```
var cellDictionary = {};
```

you'd have to do:

```
Excel.cellDictionary = {};
```

then, to access it, you'd do something like `Excel.cellDictionary["2,2"]` (maybe this is obvious)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Is it working fine?? Because for me its throwing unresponsive script error when i am running it in Firefox, its not even opening in chrome and IE.

Comment: Hmm It works fine for me in chrome with ExtJs 4.1.1, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/XGdu9/